# can't acces to columns after df.set_index

Tags: python, pandas

hello after setting index on a column of my dataframe i want to extract data that belong to this column but python shows me this error KeyError: 'airline'. airline is the title of the column in question.thnx for helping me

this is for visualizing my dataframe

```py
df_air.set_index('airline',inplace=True)
print(df_air.loc['Royal Air Maroc'])

subDf = df_air[df_air['airline'].isin(['Egyptair', 'Royal Air Maroc','Saudi Arabian']) ]
subDf
```

the 2 first command works great but when i execute the subDf it show me this error:

```
KeyError: 'airline',
```

i tried to reset my index and my problem is solved so the problem is about the index.

How can i use both of them without resetting my index?

Comment: If you set it as index, then it is of course no longer a column.

Comment: After you set a column to be an index, reference it through `df.index` instead of `df['column_name']`

Comment: i solved my problem with this:
subDf = df_air[df_air.index.to_series().isin(['Egyptair', 'Royal Air Maroc','Saudi Arabian']) ]
subDf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`airline` is no longer a column, so it cannot be accessed that way. However, you should still be able to subset like this

```
df_air.loc[['Egyptair', 'Royal Air Maroc','Saudi Arabian']]
```

Comment: They are treated as labels here using `.loc` method, so this will return rows that have these labels. you can read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: You are correct. Better solution is to slice using `df.index.isin([...])`, as you recommended ;)

Comment: i solved the probleme using df.index as said before thnx for you. for ['Egyptair', 'Royal Air Maroc','Saudi Arabian'] those are some rows on my column airline they are not columns